# Wordpress : Uncaught TypeError: $.stellar is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, stellar.js

I'm using a stellar function for parallax effect. When i used it in html file it works great. But when I added my template to Wordpress I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $.stellar is not a function
```

What is wrong and how to resolve that? Below is the code how I added scripts:

```
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/script.js"></script>
```

Regards,

Comment: Check the path that is being output. For some reason it's not finding the JS file.

Comment: What's the value of bloginfo('template_url') if you dump it?

Comment: Scripts were added correctly - I mean the path to scripts was generated correct.

Comment: Isn't that a jQuery plugin and I don't see jQuery being included before the plugin?

Comment: I adde jQuery library before. Don't forget guys that a site works with parallax script before I added site to wordpress.